# Context Window and Relation Window in source insight

Tags: source-insight

I am unable to view the context window and relation window in source window suddenly. Even if I toggle the Context Window or Relation window, it is not coming up. [issue image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mqyIW.jpg)

Comment: Best way to re-install the software

Answer (score 0):

Closing and reopening the project also fixed this issue for me.